# Can broswer api (get, post) be hidden using vue js + nuxt js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs

[I want to hide the message and request or the data in it as seen in the screen shot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpyXT.png)

Comment: in the picture you saw the packets. and no you cann't hide that info. and btw every packets which go out from your pc, not related to browser you can see with sniffer tools like wireshark. in short you cann't really hide the packets which send from your pc.

Comment: use canvas on https protocol

Comment: A friend of mine previously stated that she hides the API on the browser network by implementing ssr with nuxt js in a project, is this possible? 
I need an example to hide the data in the api request with ssr + nuxt + fetch

Comment: What your friend probably means is that they use Nuxt.js to have a server-side rendered (SSR) approach to deploying their webapp. They're not 'hiding data', they're controlling which data is being sent.
If you use SSR, you don't use an external API. You handle all the data on the server and then deploy the pages with the data already on it. This is a systemically different approach from the client-side rendering you're doing, where you render a page and then do an API request to fill that page with data. If you want to know mroe about SSR/Nuxt, they have pretty good docs. https://nuxtjs.org/